# Counting number of 11 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many even 11-digit numbers (no leading zeros) have at least three 3's?

First I tried to find the total number of 11-digit even numbers, then I have subtracted number of 11-digit numbers which have at most two 3's.

But this process looks lengthy. If there is an alternative, let me know.

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary 24 looks too less..!!!!

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary Can you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: Your approach is correct and its the easiest try using permutations and you should get your answer

Comment: I hope you subtracted the number of $11$-digit _even_ numbers with at most two $3$'s.  Note that "at most two" is $0$, $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to look separately at the cases where the first digit is or is not $3$.

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary your "solution" in your initial comment (*even if replacing C's with P's*) is very incorrect.  I recommend deleting your comment to avoid confusing more people.  You seem to have completely ignored that we are working in base ten and that we are looking for even numbers specifically.

Comment: @JMoravitz ok sir

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is a good one and is the one that I would recommend.

Let us look at the sub-problem of counting how many even 11-digit have exactly two $3$'s:

Break into cases based on whether the leading digit is a $3$ or if it is a non-$3$

- Case 1: The leading digit is a $3$

  - Set the first digit as a $3$ (*One option*)
  - Choose the final digit, it must be even (*five options*)
  - Choose the location of the remaining $3$ (*nine options*)
  - From left-to-right, choose the value of each remaining non-3 digit (*nine options each*)
- Case 2: The leading digit is not a $3$

  - Choose the first digit remembering it can't be $3$ and it can't be $0$ (*eight options*)
  - Choose the final digit, it must be even (*five options*)
  - Choose the location of the two threes (*nine choose two options*)
  - From left-to-right, choose the value of each remaining non-3 non-leading digit (*nine options each*)

> $5\cdot 9^{9}+8\cdot 5\cdot \binom{9}{2}\cdot 9^7$

Apply multiplication principle and addition principle to arrive at the total number of even 11-digit numbers containing exactly two threes.  Do so similarly for the other subproblems of having exactly one three or exactly zero threes.